# Why is my C# Writer.Write(Filelist1) only writing 1kb

Tags: c#, streamwriter

gonna start this off with  i is nub
Im Writing an application to download mods from curseforge using a list of links in a text file, when i try to write to that file with a textbox in forms using

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this code segment write data to file.
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("Addons.AMU", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
    writer.Write(FileList1);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();

}
```

however when i read the file it prints
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: (random bs gibberish here)...

why does it print up a few characters then a ....?

if i write

```
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
hello world!
```

i expect the output to be exactly that however it outputs as

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: hello world!
hello world!
hello world!....
```

Comment: You're calling `writer.Write(FileList1);`. That's trying to write the `TextBox` object itself to the writer. I suspect you meant `writer.Write(FileList1.Text);`

Comment: thanks for the help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
writer.Write(FileList1);
```

to

```
writer.Write(FileList1.Text);
```

Comment: my god that was fast
thanks for the help i really appreciate it